# Can WIX modify XML files inside an XAP package?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, wix

I am using **WIX** to automatically modify web.config files depending on the environment the user is installing. I did this using **WixUtilExtension** and a cutom "choose environment" dialog UI.

I was wondering if there is any possible way to make WIX modify xml files inside a XAP package such as **ServiceReferences.ClientConfig** file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit quirky, but most probably you will end up with a custom action that will:

1. Extract the XAP ([as a zip file](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/))
2. Load the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig from a temp folder
3. Update the config file with the user inputs
4. Re-zip it as XAP